# Is it possible to do Windows Mobile testing with robot framework?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, windows-mobile, robotframework, python-appium

Any one with hands on experience on Windows Mobile testing using Robot Framework can give me reference links or some sort of examples to start with it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't have hands on experience, but a quick search on the internet revealed [winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.StoreApps), a driver for selenium.

Translating the example on their page from python to using Selenium2LIbrary should be straight-forward. I can't test this, but using selenium2library to create a connection to the device might look something like this (using the pipe-separated format for clarity):

```
| | ${capabilities}= | create dictionary | app=C:\\testApp.appx
| | Create webdriver | Remote
| | ... | command_executor=http://localhost:0000 
| | ... | desired_capabilities=${capabilities}
```

Comment: According to the winium README, it is currently only compatible with Windows Phone, not Windows Mobile.